# Say I am in Canada and I have a U.S SSN can I open a credit line though a bank there

Tags: identity-theft

I recently got my SSN stolen and just for research was wondering if my SSN would work even if someone tried to sign up for credit in another country or if the bank their would see it's not a local SSN and basically tell them it's useless there?

Answer (score 4):

US lenders are required to clear your identity per the US patriot act, that includes clearing your address.

So ultimately it would depend on the address reporting on your credit report. Do you have credit in the US?

If a lender knows that you are living abroad they would turn down your request as there's some potential legal risks involved that banks won't assume. At least not the (major) bank where I work.

Comment: Im currently 21 and have no credit line at all. Part of me is hoping I'm useless to the person who stole my SSN

Comment: In that case there shouldn't be too much of an issue. However, since it's been stolen I would contact all three credit bureaus and either place an extended fraud alert or freeze the credit report. This will ensure that no credit applications are processed without taking further measures to verify your identity and ensure it really is you who applies.